# access history and other stuff from browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone

How would I access the history and cookies from the browser control, in currently using a listbox that adds every site from the session but it's not very reliable and won't work with a back button.

Is there also a code for a back button on windows phone? `GoBack();` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the pages you navigate in your webbrowser control, to the history stack of your application so the user can use the back button of the phone to navigate back.

I found quite an interesting article on a MSDN blog about this matter, which can be found [**here**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2011/02/04/back-button-press-when-using-webbrowser-control-in-wp7.aspx). I'll post small portions of the code a remarks.

1) Listen to WebBrowser.Navigated event;  keep track of the pages that have been visited.

```
Stack<Uri> history= new Stack<Uri>();
Uri current = null; 
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Uri previous = null;           
    if (history.Count > 0)
        previous = history.Peek();

    // This assumption is NOT always right. 
    // if the page had a forward reference that creates a loop (e.g. A->B->A ), 
    // we would not detect it, we assume it is an A -> B -> back () 
    if (e.Uri == previous)
    {
        history.Pop();                     
    }
    else
    {
        if (current != null)
            history.Push(current);                          
    }
    current = e.Uri; 
}
```

2) Listen to OnBackKeyPress on the page. If the WebBrowser has a navigation stack, cancel the backkeypress and navigate within the webbrowser control’s stack.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    if (!isPerformingCloseOperation) 
    {
        if (history.Count > 0)
        {                        
            Uri destination = history.Peek();
            webBrowser.Navigate(destination);
            // What about using script and going history.back? 
            // you can do it, but 
            // I rather use that to keep ‘track’ consistently with our stack 
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Note that there are still a few edge cases that are not implemented well.

As you can see, code is trivial, but it has an issue that is not not solved.  It can’t tell the difference between:

- Navigate(a) –> Navigate(b) –> back();
- Navigate(a) –> Navigate(b) –> Navigate(a);

To conclude, here is a summary:

- Not all apps need this integration. If you are just showing a single page, and don’t want to encourage navigation, use a UX pattern that hints the user that the UI is transient – make it look like a popup, put a close button on the popup’
- If you have an app that does encourage navigation in the browser,  consider the pattern above. Don’t do it because of the certification requirement, do it because it is intuitive to the user. That is why the requirement exists.
- If you feel that your app does not fall under one of the above, then do ask for an exception to the certification team. That said, I emphasize you should thrive to create an intuitive experience for your user. I think the two options do that best so I recommend them –as opposed to the excuse/exception route-.

I hope you can do something with this.

(Full credits to Jaime Rodriguez who wrote the blog and code. I am merely posting a digest of what he wrote.)

Comment: On "Uri destination = history.Peek();
                web.Navigate(destination);
                e.Cancel = true;" -----It red underlines "Peek();" and says its not in the dictionary

Comment: Ok, I'll look at as soon as I have access to a computer with Visual Studio.

Comment: Peek is a valid method of the Stack<T> class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w32446f.aspx .

Comment: Thank you for copying some of the text from the link. As per usual with Microsoft the link is gone.